# who do i run/execute a unix shell(ksh) script which isaved on my Windows Xp desktop

Tags: shell, unix

who do i run/execute a unix shell(ksh) script which  isaved on my Windows Xp desktop?

I have script saved on my desktop and I am using putty to remote log in and run my script. How do send the script in the unix box and run the script form there.

Thanks

Comment: And why are you storing shell script locally on XP machine that will be executed on a Unix host?

Comment: I just wrote it on a note pad and I am new to unix scripting. I tried to put it in vi editor and run it but it dosen't work that way. What is the right approach?

Comment: Better to copy/paste your script from notepad into vi (shift-insert in input mode). And then run/debug your script from unix itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can connect via putty (ssh), you can copy your script via scp. WinSCP is a fine, (Windows) user friendly client. Try that.

Comment: I don't have access rights for winSCP. I just saved it in a txt file and copied in a vi editor and tried to run it from there but it dosen't work though the path variable is fixed well.

Comment: What?????????????????????????? If you can work on the UNIX system via putty, why don't you log in, fire up vi or any other editor, that may suite your needs and write your code on the UNIX host?

Comment: I tried that but it does not work. I get error " Function or library not found." do you think i get that because the path is not set correct?

Comment: You get " Function or library not found." if you start vi or you ksh script?